# Как согласовать? «Ряд сотрудников обладают...»

Tags: согласование

Ряд сотрудников обладают ученой степенью доктора, кандидата технических наук, званием «Доцент», «Старший научный сотрудник».

Answer (score 1):

Ряд специалистов обладают ученой степенью доктора или кандидата технических наук, имеют звания доцент, старший научный сотрудник.

Пояснение: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/339926-chem-otlichaetsja-uchenaja-stepen-ot-uchenogo-zvanija.html

Существует  ученая степень  - кандидат наук и доктор наук,  ученое звание - доцент и профессор. Ученая степень присваивается после защиты диссертации, а ученое звание дается при наличии вакансии.  Если есть вакансия профессора на кафедре, то доктор наук получает звание профессора, а если нет вакансии профессора, но есть вакансия доцента, то доктор наук будет доцентом. Или кандидат наук, если нет вакансии доцента, будет старшим преподавателем до тех пор, пока не появится вакансия доцента.